# How I could reset ALL wifi/network settings

Tags: wifi

I get this error when uploading updates using wifi:

> **An error occurred while downloading the selected updates. Please check your internet connection and try again.**

How I could reset the wifi/network module. I want to reset all settings for wifi on my laptop because from time to time I have problems with wifi during Google calls or watching videos.

Unfortunately resetting NVRAM, PRAM, and SMC didn't get results.

For another laptop, wifi works well.

Comment: Do you mean "downloading" updates? Which updates?

Comment: @JBallin MacOs updates 11.5.1

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences>Network, select Wi-Fi and then click on the 'minus' button beneath it. You would need to delete all network interfaces, (I think - certainly all the active ones). That'll get rid of your existing configuration. Then click on the 'plus' button and from the drop-down menu select Wi-Fi to set up a new connection…

Comment: I did it but nothing changes. In windows we have from terminal netsh winsock reset. Do we have same in mac os?

Comment: Also i did sudo ifconfig en0 down + sudo ifconfig en0 up

Comment: Also created noe location

Comment: On some Macs, en0 is not Wi-Fi, en1 is.

Comment: You would need to delete all network interfaces, (I think - certainly all the active ones).  What is making you think that some settings aren't being reset? Maybe it's some software that was installed that's causing the problem you describe? Typically, firewall or other security software causes such problems.